# Cannot access USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, thinkpad

I cannot access the Sandisk USB I insert into my laptop's USB port. It was working fine just yesterday, but now it's not showing up in My Computer.

It shows up in Devices and Printers, but there is a yellow exclamation mark on the icon. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the WPD FileSystem Volume Driver, but still the same problem.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a different USB port? Is the drive listed in the Device Manager? What's the reported error?

Comment: Code 10 is the reported error. I think that is a generic windows error, so Windows doesn't really know what's going on. I have tried it  on different ports. The USB works fine on other computers, just not my laptop. Other flash drives and external drives work fine. Device is not listed in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have found on my Win 7 Computer that Windows "forgets" to allocate a Drive letter to a USB Device.  I use the Microsoft Management Console Disk Management Utility to add a drive letter.  As soon a it is assigned the drive should pop p with a message asking you want to do with the device.